# LXD Container/What's the Preferred Way of Accessing Files from Host

Tags: container, lxd

I can access files inside a LXD container by running lxc from the host:

```
root@Host# lxc exec Container_Name bash
root@Container_Name# touch /tmp/hello
```

Or by accessing the files directly from the host under /var/lib/lxd/containers/Container_Name/rootfs:

```
root@Host# touch /var/lib/lxd/containers/Container_Name/rootfs/tmp/hello
```

Is there a preferred way?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to achieve. If you only want to create a file, the second example is totally fine. If you want to automate this process for multiple containers, have a look at cloud-init.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the exec command so that permissions will be set according to the user/group mapping of the container.